# Как используя регулярные выражения, найти строки в середине которых нет '/'

Tags: python, python-3.x, re

Я попробовал так, не получилось.

```
def main():
        driver.get('https://foundation.app/nfts?sortOrder=DEFAULT')
        html = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        assets = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'^(?<![/])(@)'))
        print(assets)

<a class="st--c-PJLV st--c-kFlVdX st--c-dfeWsk st--c-dfeWsk-begQET-variant-primary st--c-dfeWsk-eaAadL-cv" href="/@uncaream"</a>
<a class="st--c-PJLV st--c-kFlVdX st--c-dfeWsk st--c-cUZina" href="/@uncaream/cestlavie/5"</a>
```

**Мне нужно найти только "/@uncaream".**

Comment: Приведите пример строки которая должна находиться, и какие находятся у вас

Comment: ниже кода я приложил две строки и то что нужно я тоже написал

Comment: Судя по тому что вы написали строки `/cestlavie`  и `/5` тоже должны быть найдены